# Basic JavaScript Syntax

Tags: javascript, reactjs, javascript-objects

I have some questions about JavaScript Syntax and looking forward to understand them.

First: I don't understand about this syntax below,

```
{
    Key: () => function()
}
```

Example in real project:

```
// Define URL routes
// See https://github.com/flatiron/director
var routes = {
    '/': () => render(require('./components/pages/Index')),
    '/privacy': () => render(require('./components/pages/Privacy'))
};
```

it has been used in https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit/blob/master/src/app.js

What it supposes to do?

Is it the same as `{ Key: function() {} }` ?

Second: About function in JavaScript Object,

```
{
    function() {}
}
```

Example in real project:

```
var HomePage = React.createClass({
    statics: {
        layout: App
    },
    componentWillMount() {
        PageActions.set({title: 'React.js Starter Kit'});
    },
    render() {
        return (.....);
    }
});
```

it has been used in https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit/blob/master/src/components/pages/Index.js

I would like to appreciate for your answer to explaining why these are valid or if you could send me to the right information on these syntax for JavaScript object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the new way of writing function in ES6 (the next version of JavaScript).
You can find more information [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

ES6 is currently not really supported (see this [table](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/)) so you will need to compile your ES6 in ES5. (Happening [here](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit/blob/master/gulpfile.js#L62), with the flag "harmony" in your example) to make it run in your browser.

Basically:

`var test = () => {}` is the same as `var test = function() {}.bind(this)`

and

`componentWillMount() {}` is the same as `componentWillMount:function() {}`

Answer (score 2):

> Is it the same as { Key: function() {} }

Not exactly, but sort of. It's a new function syntax introduced in ECMAScript 6. The behavior is somewhat different though.

Most notably, the value of `this` in the function will adopt the value of `this` from the environment where the function was created, so it's not based on how the function is invoked like the old syntax.

The function is still a first class object and creates a closure, so there's no difference in that regard. Also, the `return` operator can be elided if the function body consists of only a single expression statement.

As @HeadCode pointed out, the `new` operator is not permitted to be used with this function, so it's not meant for constructing objects. I also want to say that it has proper tail call optimization, but I'm not sure about that.

---

The rest of the syntax is just a typical object except that it uses a new shorthand for method assignment.

Here's the MDN documentation for the fat arrow function syntax: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

And here's the MDN docs for the object initializer syntax. See the ECMAScript6 part for the new syntax: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer

Comment: There is a difference in that using the new operator with a fat arrow function will result in a TypeError.  http://robcee.net/2013/fat-arrow-functions-in-javascript/

Comment: What about `componentWillMount()` in the second part of the question? Is that equivalent to `componentWillMount: function()`?

Comment: Could you add references to the appropriate sections of the ECMAScript 6 spec?

Comment: @Barmar: That threw me off. At first it looked like the ECMAScript 5 getter syntax for object initializers, but now I see it doesn't have the `get`. I think it's a shorthand method assignment syntax that is complementary to the new `class` stuff, but I don't know all the details.

Comment: @Barmar: Added MDN refs for fat arrow functions and for object initializer syntax.

Comment: Ooh, the new computed property name syntax in ES6 is nice.

Comment: `componentWillMount` is what I thought. It's just shorthand for a property whose value is a function.

Comment: `componentWillMount() {...}` is a *method definition*. It's supported in class bodies and object literals.

Comment: @Barmar: Yeah, that's going to by very handy.